# php array doesnt write to file as expected

Tags: php, arrays, fwrite

basically im reading everything from my file, pushing it to array, and then rewriting the file with arrays so no data is lost

This is my text file after i write array. Pirmadienis,Antradienis,etc are stored on different arrays. When i write "Pirmadienis" array it starts in second line and pushed the other one to side.

```
Pirmadienis
"array fwrite here" Antradienis
Treciadienis
Ketvirtadienis
Penktadienis
```

This is php i use. $pirm is an array for "Pirmadienis". I use 4 more foreach loops so each array is writen into file. Any ideas why its creating a new line?

```
$file = fopen($failas,"w+");
foreach($pirm as $key => $value) {
fwrite($file,$value); 
}
```

Comment: off topic, what about json_encode or serialize? seems like a better solution for writing to files

Comment: I need to do this way. Can this actually use whole line as the length parameter is too long? content = fgets($file,4096);

Comment: I'm not sure if you are talking the problem is it writes in same line... If yes justneed to add the new line chars...so use fwrite($file,trim($value)."\r\n");  (use trim to ensure don't have 2 endlines)

Comment: No dude. "array writes here" this should be on first line, i dont know how it goes to second line. I didnt specify any new line parameters for it to do so.

Comment: Anyway trim worked somehow thanks alot. #solved